# Inset Shadow to a curve bottom ta

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to add an inset shadow to the bottom tabs below:
[bottom tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si0lo.png)

does anyone knows how can I make this please?

> Note: I am using react native expo